# How to extract JSON value through SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, extract

"example_code": [
{
"code": "blah",
"type": "value"
}
]

In other cases we would write : (meta->'example_code'->'code')

But, since it is inside [] braces, i am not able to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Since `example_code` is an array use `-> 0`  to access its first (and only) element. Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) on it.
CTE `the_table` is a mimic of real data.

```sql
with the_table(meta) as 
(
 values ('{"example_code":[{"code":"blah", "type":"value"}]}'::json)
)
select meta -> 'example_code' -> 0 ->> 'code' from the_table;
```